# How to insert a character after each set of digits in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Based on the simple jQuery/JavasScript code below, when a link is clicked, it gets the links `class` name and removes the word `sign` so that **sign24x10** becomes **24x10**

What I would like to do is also insert `"` after the 24 and after the 10 as well as a space.  So that **24x10** becomes **24" x 10"**  Keep in mind there will be a large number of these so the number value will always be different.

Can someone show me a way to modify what I have to make the new described additions work?  Thanks

```
<a href="sign24x10" class="sign24x10">
    <small style="height: 50px; width: 120px;"></small>Size 24" x 10"
</a>

$("#sign-size-boxes a").on("click", function(e){
    signSizeStr = $(this).attr('class').replace("sign", "");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use a plain ol' regex.

```
$("#sign-size-boxes a").on("click", function(e){
    matches = $(this).attr('class').match(/sign([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)/);
    signSizeStr = matches[1] + '" x ' + matches[2] + '"';
});
```

Comment: I see several good solutions here and I am not sure which is the "Best" but I have decided to go along with this one for now, thanks to you and the others

Comment: @jasondavis I'd argue that mine is better because it avoids the unnecessary interim step. There's no reason to match and then build the string by hand if `replace` can do this in one step. However, it's not really much of a difference and this answer is absolutely fine to be accepted. Glad you looked at the other ones as well!

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expresions for this:

```
signSizeStr = $(this).attr('class')
    .replace("sign", "")
    .replace(/(\d+)x(\d+)/g, '$1" x $2"');
```

Or in one call

```
signSizeStr = $(this).attr('class')
    .replace(/sign(\d+)x(\d+)/g, '$1" x $2"');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just split by `x`. Then concat, something like below

```
var a = '24x10';
var x = a.split('x');
x[0]+'" x '+x[1]+'"' // this should give you 24" x 10"
```

Note : Its a demo code, please change it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Append the following code in your function

> arrTmp = signSizeStr.split("x")
>
> newStr = arrTmp[0] + '" x ' + arrTmp[1] + '"'

Comment: The first line of code will split the string signSizeStr into an array, using "x" as a separator. The next line of code basically concatenates the 2 elements of the array with the desired symbols like  ", x and appropriate whitespaces

Comment: You are missing trailing semicolons which is considered bad practice. You declare implicit globals which is bad practice and dangerous. And you claim it's a drop-in snippet which it simply isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You could just call replace once more.

```
signSizeStr = $(this).attr('class').replace("sign", "").replace("x",'" x ') + '"';
```